# Организовать уведомление о новом действии в Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Здравствуйте. Допустим, имеем определенное действие, к примеру заказ.
Нужно сделать уведомление о том, если поступил новый заказ во вкладке сайта(к примеру: звуковое, не суть).

Как вижу это я:

1. Добавить столбец в БД `unread`, при добавлении заказа присваивать ему 1.
2. Сделать `action`, который если есть новые заказы - возвращает их число, если нет - возвращается `null`.
3. С помощью jQuery+AJAX проверять новые заказы используя `setInterval`.
4. Если есть новый заказ - уведомлять. Также появляется кнопка "Отметить прочитанным" - при её нажатии все заказы с `unread` содержащим 1 принимают значение 0.

Какие подводные камни? Возможно, есть варианты получше?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Ну кроме того, что в цикле постоянно будут идти запросы к базе, вариант вполне рабочий

Comment: а почему бы на стороне бд не сделать тригер, который бы срабатывал как раз таки при заданных вами условяиях?